# Fake Linux System Time Within a Unit Test

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, datetime

I am unit testing a function that uses the current time. Because of this, I am looking for a way to fake the system time. I understand there are libraries that change the system time, but I am looking for any less invasive, simple alternatives for a small unit test.

Does anything similar to this exist?:

```
TEST_T(MyUnitTest, example_test){

    startFakeSystemDate("2017-3-13T18:12:49Z");

    //perform time based unit test

    endFakeSystemDate();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the way around this be to write a function that gets the system time, then mock that function in your tests?

Comment: How do I mock the get system time function in my tests?

Comment: There's the [warp](https://github.com/att/ast/blob/master/src/cmd/warp/PROMO.mm) software. It's a C file that produces a shared object with an alternative `time` and `gettimeofday` (and others) and a shell script that uses LD_PRELOAD to run your executable with that shared object.